# "Failed to build gem native extension" when installing xively-rb for raspberry Pi

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install the `xively` Ruby gem on the Raspberry Pi - http://rubygems.org/gems/xively-rb

However, during install the following occurs:

> gem install xively-rb Building native extensions.  This could take a
>   while... ERROR:  Error installing xively-rb:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0/ext/yajl/gem_make.out

I'm pretty sure I fixed this issue on Windows by install the dev version of ruby, but executing `rvm list` shows that I have the correct versions installed:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.1-p431-dev [ armv6l ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ armv6l ]    
   ruby-2.0.0-p353-dev [ armv6l ]

Where =* denotes the currently used ruby version.
```

How can I correct my setup to install `xively`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the log file that got generated when you attempted to compile this Ruby gem. The log file is a little hard to tease out of the above output but it will likely tell you why the compilation of this Gem failed.

```
$ more /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
```

A couple of guesses as to why this might be happening:

- Xively only works with certain versions of Ruby
- Tools such as `gcc` or some lower level library may be missing on your system
- Gem will only build on certain platforms (i.e. might not compile on Raspbery Pi on ARM architecture)

If you find an issue make sure to report back to the maintainer/developer of Xively so that they can fix the underlying issue and make their Gem better!

- https://github.com/xively/xively-rb

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure I checked the log file and it contained "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb" which I didn't think was very helpful, but I'll double check

Comment: @barry - please pastebin it if you can, I'd like to take a look at it either way.

Comment: Will do - it'll be this evening

Comment: I'm afraid the contents of the log file are simply "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb"

Comment: @barry - are you doing a `gem install xively`? I do happen to have a Rasp Pi box so if I have time I could try your command there. I use OpenElec though for my OS

Comment: I'm doing `gem install xively-rb` on Occidentals